# Adding a second input to Vite causes the build to creat a non-functional page

Tags: javascript, jquery, vite, rollupjs

### The Goal

I would like to use Vite to build my application with a main single page app plus an additional error page that has the same look & feel and can be bundled together. Everything works great until I try to add an the second input to the build.

While I could just hardcode the error page I would like the header and footer to update when it is updated in the single page app. To accomplish this I have a template that includes html, js, and css. I run a pre-build script and it places the guts of my application into the template. I then run vite on the assembled page to bundle the files for deployment. This bundles the js and css from the template and application together. I know this is a somewhat atypical use of Vite but for reasons irrelevant to this problem this is the way it must be.

This works great when I bundle my single page app without the error page. Here is my single page only vite.config.js:

```
export default defineConfig({
    base: './',
    server: {
        open: './index.html
    },
    plugins: [
        inlineSource(),
        ],
    build: {
        emptyOutDir: true,
        outDir: "../dist",
        rollupOptions: {
            input: {
                main: resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'),
            },
        }
    },
})
```

### The Problem

The problem occurs when I add the error page as a second input. Here is that vite.config.js:

```
export default defineConfig({
    base: './',
    server: {
        open: './index.html
    },
    plugins: [
        inlineSource(),
        ],
    build: {
        emptyOutDir: true,
        outDir: "../dist",
        rollupOptions: {
            input: {
                main: resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'),
                err: resolve(__dirname, '404.html'),
            },
        }
    },
})
```

The only change is that line beginning with "err".

When I add this second input the build "succeeds" with no errors but the index.html page has a runtime error and no longer functions.

Loading index.html in a browser I see this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` which seems to be due to a commonjs include being used in a es module context. The obvious solution if to just update the code but here's the catch, the problematic code is part of the dynamically generated template and cannot be changed. This is also likely a distraction from the real problem.

### The heart of the problem:

Why do I only get this error when I have a second input? It is the same template and if I remove the second input it works again. The index.html should work the same as it always has but somehow the build is breaking it. It seems like all of this is a failure of vite/rollup to properly build when a second input is added. Perhaps I need to configure it better but I'm unsure how to address this issue and I've already spent a whole day struggling with it.

I know that when there are two or more inputs there is a common.js file where the shared resources are placed in addition to a file containing the the code unique to each page. It, however, isn't obvious why this is causing the page to no longer work.

### Other things I've tried

Since the error seemed to have something to do with this require statement I tries the commonjs plugin which did resolve the `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` error. It, however, introduces another runtime error that occurs even when I try to only bundle index.html, `Uncaught TypeError: s.event is undefined`. This seems related to jQuery (actually jQuery migrate), which makes sense since that is what the require was trying to import. (yes, I'm sorry, the template engine uses jQuery. I hate it too.) This error has been very difficult to resolve, if it even can be resolved.

I've also tried to specify only the necessary files for the commonjs plugin but it still created these issues. Something like:

```
commonjs({
     include: [ /jquery-migrate.min/]
}),
```

Reading through the documentation for Vite and Rollup also provided no obvious solution. Has anyone here had an issue like this? Were you able to resolve it? How?

I never thought it would be so difficult to add a simple error page to this application.